# menu in Firefox: click menuitem is ignored

Tags: css, firefox, css-position

I'm trying to make an actions menu, my implementation works great in Chrome and Edge, but not in Firefox in the sense that it seems to totally ignore menuitems' substance, clicks going through them and triggering items below the menu...

In the codepen hovering a menuitem shouldnot trigger the hover of the article below, and clicking should trigger the close menu event.

I really don't understand why and what i'm missing ...
I tried with overflow: visible on the button parent, the nav, but nada...
I also tried putting the nav in the section container, but still same problem ...

[FULL code on Codepen](http://codepen.io/Sharlaan/pen/qmoJbY)

> CSS

```
section {
border: 1px solid red;
padding: 20px;
width: 300px;
}

header {
border: 1px solid blue;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
padding: 10px;
}

header > h3 { margin: 0; }

header > button {
display: block;
position: relative;
overflow: visible;
}

nav {
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
z-index: 2;
background-color: lightyellow;
overflow: visible;
}

.showMenu {
display: block;
}

.menuitem {
white-space: nowrap;
border: 1px solid transparent;
padding: 5px;
width: 100px;
}

.menuitem:hover {
cursor: pointer;
border-color: red;
}

section > div {
border: 1px solid green;
padding: 10px;
}

article {
display: block;
height: 30px;
border: 1px solid black;
}

article:not(:last-child) {
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

article:hover {
background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

> JS

```
const button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0]

const menu = document.getElementsByTagName('nav')[0]

const menuItems = document.getElementsByClassName('menuitem')

button.addEventListener('click', function () {
menu.classList.toggle('showMenu')
})

button.addEventListener('blur', function (event) {
if (!this.contains(event.relatedTarget)) {
     menu.classList.toggle('showMenu')
}
})

for (let mi of menuItems) {
  mi.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  event.stopPropagation()
  menu.classList.toggle('showMenu')
})
}
```

> HTML

```
<section>
 <header>
  <h3>HEADER</h3>
  <button>
     <span>menu</span>
     <nav>
        <div class="menuitem">ITEM 1</div>
        <div class="menuitem">ITEM 2</div>
        <div class="menuitem">ITEM 3</div>
        <div class="menuitem">ITEM 4</div>
        <div class="menuitem">ITEM 5</div>
        <div class="menuitem">ITEM 6</div>
     </nav>
  </button>
</header>
<div>
  <article>ARTICLE 1</article>
  <article>ARTICLE 2</article>
  <article>ARTICLE 3</article>
  <article>ARTICLE 4</article>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Include your code in the post itself please, don't just link to codepen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on itacode's response, a `button`'s content model is phrasing content, so you can't have a `nav` in a `button` https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#the-button-element

You said you tried putting `nav` in `section` and it didn't work - works for me though.

```js
const button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0]

const menu = document.getElementsByTagName('nav')[0]

const menuItems = document.getElementsByClassName('menuitem')

button.addEventListener('click', function () {
   menu.classList.toggle('showMenu')
})

for (let mi of menuItems) {
   mi.addEventListener('click', function () {
      menu.classList.toggle('showMenu')
   })
}
```

```css
section {
   border: 1px solid red;
   padding: 20px;
   width: 300px;
}

header {
   border: 1px solid blue;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
   padding: 10px;
   position: relative;
}

header > h3 { margin: 0; }

header > button {
   display: block;
   position: relative;
   overflow: visible;
}

nav {
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   top: calc(100% - 10px);
   right: 0;
   z-index: 2;
   background-color: lightyellow;
   overflow: visible;
}

.showMenu {
   display: block;
}

.menuitem {
   white-space: nowrap;
   border: 1px solid transparent;
   padding: 5px;
   width: 100px;
}

.menuitem:hover {
   cursor: pointer;
   border-color: red;
}

section > div {
   border: 1px solid green;
   padding: 10px;
}

article {
   display: block;
   height: 30px;
   border: 1px solid black;
}

article:not(:last-child) {
   margin-bottom: 10px;
}

article:hover {
   background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<section>
   <header>
      <h3>HEADER</h3>
      <button>
         <span>OPEN</span>
         
      </button>
      <nav>
            <div class="menuitem">ITEM 1</div>
            <div class="menuitem">ITEM 2</div>
            <div class="menuitem">ITEM 3</div>
            <div class="menuitem">ITEM 4</div>
            <div class="menuitem">ITEM 5</div>
            <div class="menuitem">ITEM 6</div>
         </nav>
   </header>
   <div>
      <article>ARTICLE 1</article>
      <article>ARTICLE 2</article>
      <article>ARTICLE 3</article>
      <article>ARTICLE 4</article>
   </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because the dropdown menu is inside the button. It is incorrect to use a nav tag inside a button. Please place the nav outside, give position relative to header and adjust the absolute position of nav.